# How to assign colors and line types of multiple vertical lines in each plot in the sapply function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sapply

[image]I generated multiple plots with vertical lines in each plot using the following codes:
I was wondering if there's any way to change colours and line types of each vertical lines on this codes:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)

vertical.lines <- c(1990,1991)


df1 %>%
  filter(isocode == "KOR") %>%
  select(year,rgdpe, rgdpo, avh, emp, hc) %>%
  tidyr::gather(predictor, value, -year)%>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(year, value))+ 
  facet_wrap(~predictor, scales = "free")+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, top = "Title of the Chart",
  bottom = textGrob(
    "Data source: World Bank",
    gp = gpar(fontface = 3, fontsize = 9),
    hjust = 1,x = 1))+ sapply(vertical.lines, function(xint) geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xint)))
```

I want to put something like
`lty = c(3,1), color  = c("blue","red"), lwd=c(.5,.5))`

But I don't know how to apply to my code.

My data looks like to have the structure like the following
Maybe if you need, I can add more variables.

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Aruba", 
"Angola", "Anguilla", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", 
"Armenia", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Burundi", "Belgium", "Benin", "Burkina Faso", "Bangladesh", 
"Bulgaria", "Bahrain", "Bahamas", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Belarus", 
"Belize", "Bermuda", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Brazil", 
"Barbados", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bhutan", "Botswana", "Central African Republic", 
"Canada", "Switzerland", "Chile", "China", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cameroon", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo", "Colombia", "Comoros", 
"Cabo Verde", "Costa Rica", "Curacao", "Cayman Islands", "Cyprus", 
"Czech Republic", "Germany", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Denmark", 
"Dominican Republic", "Algeria", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "Spain", 
"Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "Fiji", "France", "Gabon", 
"United Kingdom", "Georgia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Gambia", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Equatorial Guinea", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guyana", 
"China, Hong Kong SAR", "Honduras", "Croatia", "Haiti", "Hungary", 
"Indonesia", "India", "Ireland", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", 
"Iraq", "Iceland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Jordan", "Japan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kyrgyzstan", "Cambodia", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", 
"Republic of Korea", "Kuwait", "Lao People's DR", "Lebanon", 
"Liberia", "Saint Lucia", "Sri Lanka", "Lesotho", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Latvia", "China, Macao SAR", "Morocco", "Republic of Moldova", 
"Madagascar", "Maldives", "Mexico", "North Macedonia", "Mali", 
"Malta", "Myanmar", "Montenegro", "Mongolia", "Mozambique", "Mauritania", 
"Montserrat", "Mauritius", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Namibia", "Niger", 
"Nigeria", "Nicaragua", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Nepal", "New Zealand", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", 
"Portugal", "Paraguay", "State of Palestine", "Qatar", "Romania", 
"Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saudi Arabia", "Sudan", "Senegal", 
"Singapore", "Sierra Leone", "El Salvador", "Serbia", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Suriname", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Sweden", "Eswatini", "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)", 
"Seychelles", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Turks and Caicos Islands", 
"Chad", "Togo", "Thailand", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Taiwan", "U.R. of Tanzania: Mainland", 
"Uganda", "Ukraine", "Uruguay", "United States of America", "Uzbekistan", 
"St. Vincent & Grenadines", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"British Virgin Islands", "Viet Nam", "Yemen", "South Africa", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), isocode = c("ABW", 
"ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW"), year = 1990:1994, currency = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Algerian Dinar", "Argentine Peso", 
"Armenian Dram", "Aruban Guilder", "Australian Dollar", "Azerbaijanian Manat", 
"Bahamian Dollar", "Bahraini Dinar", "Baht", "Balboa", "Barbados Dollar", 
"Belarussian Ruble", "Belize Dollar", "Bermudian Dollar", "Bolivar Fuerte", 
"Boliviano", "Brazilian Real", "Brunei Dollar", "Bulgarian Lev", 
"Burundi Franc", "CFA Franc BCEAO", "CFA Franc BEAC", "Cabo Verde Escudo", 
"Canadian Dollar", "Cayman Islands Dollar", "Cedi", "Chilean Peso", 
"Colombian Peso", "Comoro Franc", "Convertible Marks", "Cordoba Oro", 
"Costa Rican Colon", "Croatian Kuna", "Czech Koruna", "Dalasi", 
"Danish Krone", "Denar", "Djibouti Franc", "Dobra", "Dominican Peso", 
"Dong", "East Caribbean Dollar", "Egyptian Pound", "Ethiopian Birr", 
"Euro", "Fiji Dollar", "Forint", "Franc Congolais", "Gourde", 
"Guarani", "Guinea Franc", "Guyana Dollar", "Hong Kong Dollar", 
"Hryvnia", "Iceland Krona", "Indian Rupee", "Iranian Rial", "Iraqi Dinar", 
"Jamaican Dollar", "Jordanian Dinar", "Kenyan Shilling", "Kip", 
"Kuwaiti Dinar", "Kwacha", "Kwanza", "Kyat", "Lari", "Lebanese Pound", 
"Lek", "Lempira", "Leone", "Lilangeni", "Loti", "Malagasy Ariary", 
"Malaysian Ringgit", "Manat", "Mauritius Rupee", "Metical", "Mexican Peso", 
"Moldovan Leu", "Moroccan Dirham", "Naira", "Namibian Dollar", 
"Nepalese Rupee", "Netherlands Antillian Guilder", "New Israeli Sheqel", 
"New Leu", "New Taiwan Dollar", "New Turkish Lira", "New Zealand Dollar", 
"Ngultrum", "Norwegian Krone", "Nuevo Sol", "Ouguiya", "Pakistan Rupee", 
"Pataca", "Peso Uruguayo", "Philippine Peso", "Pound Sterling", 
"Pula", "Qatari Rial", "Quetzal", "Rand", "Rial Omani", "Riel", 
"Rufiyaa", "Rupiah", "Russian Ruble", "Rwanda Franc", "Saudi Riyal", 
"Serbian Dinar", "Seychelles Rupee", "Singapore Dollar", "Som", 
"Somoni", "Sri Lanka Rupee", "Sudanese Pound", "Surinam Dollar", 
"Swedish Krona", "Swiss Franc", "Syrian Pound", "Taka", "Tanzanian Shilling", 
"Tenge", "Trinidad and Tobago Dollar", "Tugrik", "Tunisian Dinar", 
"UAE Dirham", "US Dollar", "Uganda Shilling", "Uzbekistan Sum", 
"Won", "Yemeni Rial", "Yen", "Yuan Renminbi", "Zloty"), class = "factor"), 
    rgdpe = c(2574.41870117188, 2803.42724609375, 2943.32641601562, 
    3130.13989257812, 3535.80346679688), rgdpo = c(3043.74633789062, 
    3204.01831054688, 3399.08251953125, 3711.45483398438, 4192.33935546875
    ), pop = c(0.062149, 0.064622, 0.068235, 0.072504, 0.0767
    ), emp = c(NA, 0.0292000006884336, 0.030903272330761, 0.0329118072986603, 
    0.0348959788680077), avh = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), hc = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c("ABW-1990", "ABW-1991", 
"ABW-1992", "ABW-1993", "ABW-1994"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Sure, I just put the data sample.

Comment: I made a change on my codes in order to make them more fit to the data sample I provided above. hopefully it makes better.

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `purrr::pmap` or `mapply` which both allow you to loop over multiple vectors or lists simultaneously.

Additionally, if you want to add title and/or caption you could do so via the `title` and `caption` arguments of `labs()`and set the style via `theme` options.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>%
  select(year, rgdpe, rgdpo, avh, emp, hc) %>%
  tidyr::gather(predictor, value, -year) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(year, value)) +
  facet_wrap(~predictor, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = "Title of the Chart", caption = "Data source: World Bank") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(face = 3, size = 9, hjust = 1)) +
  purrr::pmap(
    data.frame(
      xint = c(1990, 1991),
      lty = c(3, 1),
      color = c("blue", "red")
    ),
    function(xint, lty, color, lwd) geom_vline(xintercept = xint, color = color, linetype = lty, size = .5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but when I add more years on the data, the plot is supposed to show smooth curve but the code generates a discrete style of line in each plot. is there any way to fix this issue? I add some more years so that you may see what's going on. Thanks again.

Comment: Hm. When I run the code with the updated data I see that your black line is not a smooth line. But that's a different issue than what you asked for in your question which was about how to add vertical lines with different colors and linewidth.

Comment: I agree. I thought smooth line wouldn't be an issue because my original code successfully generated the smooth curve. Can you figure out what's the problem? Thanks. I will update the question right away so that I can show you how the graphs are supposed to be look like.

Comment: Hey Joe. Reminds me of the song by Jimi Hendrix. :D I don't see any issue with the smooth lines. As far as I get it that looks like a normal time series plot with an annual frequency. Concerning the titles for the plot. As you are faceting I guess you mean the titles of the facets, right? To change that you could do `facet_wrap(..., labeller = labeller(predictor = c(avh = "Label AVH", emp = "Label EMP", ...)))`.

Comment: thanks Stefan, sorry but I don't quite get what you mean because still graphs from you code do not exactly look like the plots above that I newly added. Would you mind if you would explain more?

Comment: One point. I changed your code slightly by dropping the `filter(isocode == "KOR")` statement. Reason was that your snippet does not include `KOR`ea. Maybe that's the issue? Because otherwise my code will simply add the vertical lines and should have no effect on how the line plotted via the `geom_line`.

Comment: `filter()` is required because the plot is for the designated country KOR. And even without KOR, the plot is the same way. Is there any way to make the plot simply look like the on the top with only different line colors and shapes? Sorry I don't see your point.